# xrdp fails from Windows 11 to CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos

I am trying to take a remote desktop connection from Windows 11 to CentOS Stream 9 running on Hyper V.

Below is the error msg:

[image]

Link to view [xrdp.ini](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqin2ntpay1p8ew/xrdp.ini?dl=0)

Thanks!

Comment: If the RDP client runs on Windows 11 why don't you just use Microsoft's RDP client (the client initiates the connection so it is the "from" and the server is the "to" or did you made a mistake at that point in your question?).

Comment: I am using Microsoft RDP client to connect. The screenshot above is shown after entering the session.

Comment: Check the log file(s) of xrdp,. The "log" shown in the screenshot is just the user info dialog, not a real log.

Comment: i have same problem (never used GUI linux before). probably need to ask in superuser instead - linux admins are so very snarky on SF.. (genetically modified ill tempered seabass comes to mind)